# Error in Parsing JSON in Python (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Pandas and I have to parse a JSON file from inside Jupyter Notebook.
Here is the content of `books.json`

```
[
    {
        "writer": "Mark Ross",
        "nationality": "USA",
        "books": [
            {
                "title": "XML Cookbook",
                "price": 23.56
            },
            {
                "title": "Python Fundamentals",
                "price": 50.70
            },
            {
                "title": "The NumPy library",
                "price": 12.30
            }
        ]
    },
    
    {
        "writer": "Barbara Bracket",
        "nationality": "UK",
        "books": [
             {
                "title": "Java Enterprise",
                "price": 28.60
            },
            {
                "title": "HTML5",
                "price": 31.35
            },
            {
                "title": "Python for Dummies",
                "price": 28.00
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I try the code below via Jupyter Notebook,

```
import json
file = open('./books.json', 'r')
text = file.read()
text = json.loads(text)
```

I got an error on the last line of the block of code above

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_5338/2028572637.py in <module>
----> 1 text = json.loads(text)

/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358     if cls is None:
    359         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have tried to read the file and re-writing it into another JSON file, stripping spaces and tabs in this case, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The final error it throws means that the `text` is empty.
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

This exact error is returned when the `text` is empty.
Note, the JSON value you provided passes online JSON validators, and it would've thrown a different error if the issue is in the JSON itself.

Try loading the json file as follows.

```py
with open(filename) as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

Note, I changed the name from `text` to `data` to avoid confusion about the contents of the variable.